# Android Espresso fails AssertionFailedWithCauseError

Tags: android, android-espresso, ui-testing

I am trying to run an Android Espresso test on a layout that contains multiple `EditTexts`. Each `EditText` has a unique `id`. My test successfully clears the text from each `EditText`, but it fails to replace the text with my `String` (`stringToBeTyped = "123 Sesame St."`).

This same test is also being run successfully on other layouts that have just one `EditText` each. My hunch is that there may be a bug in Espresso related to multiple `EditTexts` per layout.

My test method:

```
void performEditTextComparisonAndModificationTest(int resId, String initialText, String stringToBeTyped) {
    onView(withId(resId)).check(matches(withText(initialText)));
    onView(withId(resId)).perform(click(), replaceText(stringToBeTyped));
    onView(withId(resId)).check(matches(withText(stringToBeTyped)));
}
```

My logcat output:

```
android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: 'with text: is "123 Sesame St."' doesn't match the selected view.
Expected: with text: is "123 Sesame St."
Got: "EditText{id=3, visibility=VISIBLE, width=432, height=49, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=true, editor-info=[inputType=0x2071 imeOptions=0x8000005 privateImeOptions=null actionLabel=null actionId=0 initialSelStart=0 initialSelEnd=0 initialCapsMode=0x2000 hintText=Street Address label=null packageName=null fieldId=0 fieldName=null extras=null ], x=0.0, y=0.0, text=, hint=Street Address, input-type=8305, ime-target=false, has-links=false}"
```

As you can see from the end of the third logcat line, the `EditText`'s text="". Why is this? Could it be a bug in the espresso framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace  `onView(withId(resId)).perform(click(), replaceText(stringToBeTyped));`

with

```
onView(withId(resId)).perform(click(), clearText(), replaceText(stringToBeTyped));
```

It looks like it might be saving the hint text and not properly replacing the string.

**Edit:**

On second look, I think you are trying to match the string in your final step to the resId which is why you are getting 'Expected: 123 sesame, Got: EditText' Try this:

```
onView(allOf(withId(resId), withText(stringToBeTyped))).check(matches(withText(stringToBeTyped)));
```

Comment: Thanks. This updated test still passes for the other Activities that only have one `EditText` but it still fails for this case. It has the same exact log output.